# Xamarin for Mac won't launch Activity

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, android-activity

In trying to debug an Android app in Visual Studio Community (7.7.4) on Mac Os, I'm getting an error below.

User assembly '/Users/.../PublicKeysGen.exe' is missing. Debugger will now debug all code, not just user code.

am start -n "com.x.x/...MainActivity"
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.x.x/...MainActivity }

Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.x.x/...MainActivity} does not exist.

The app does install on the device and does work but VS can't launch it and I can't debug. I can use the app normally in the simulator or on a device, just not while connected to VS. I noticed the app manifest file does not include the package name before the md5 hash.MainActivity but I doubt this is the issue because the app does work on the device.

The iOS version works fine in all scenarios.

I realize this question has been asked here before but none of the solutions are working for me. One thing to note, I took this project over from another developer. I received a zip file with the project in it and started from there. Any thoughts?

Comment: I had a similar problem and to fix it: I delete all "bin" and "obj" folders; I clean again the project and I set again my android version in property setup to a old one.
Good lucky

Comment: Can you check in the settings if the app already exists in the device, look for it in the installed apps and look for your application name or your package name